# How to execute argocd cli in aws lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, argocd

Before, I have used a lambda layer to use psycopg2.
Because psycopg2 is python library, I just imported psycopg2.

But, as far as I know, There is no library for executing argocd cli.
So I'm asking way to use argocd command in lambda (python 3.8)

I searched python library, but nothing.